# Accessing raw phone call data on Android

Tags: android, gsm, telephony

I'm working on an app to cipher the audio stream sent via a voice call. Not VoIP call, just regular GSM phone call.

I have put together all of the core Android code classes to recreate the whole process of making a phone call but I always hit a dead spot where I can follow no longer.

Essentially, what need to know is: Where does Android manager the data that is being sent through a phone call. I mean were the bytes sent are.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In very (over..) simple terms an Android phones consists of a general purpose processor which runs the Android OS and is similar to a regular 'computer' and dedicated hardware including a 'baseband' processor that handles the Mobile Phone communications.

The interface between the Android world and the GSM/UMTS phone world is tightly defined and the Android side has only limited access to the 'phone' side. This is for security and reliability reasons - e.g. it avoids a 'bad' app being able to take the phone down, which could have very serious consequences in emergency call situations.

The normal interface into the telephony side from Android is:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm sure there is a low level way through the RIL or using AT Commands to manage the data. I'll keep on searching.

Comment: Do you mean data or voice stream? If you mean the voice stream, then just a quick note that the voice stream is already encrypted between the handset and the base station, in case you were not aware.